# Rails Admin use Html in Enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I want to display a field in the admin where the user can select some font awesome icons. So what I do at the moment is:

```
  field :icon, :enum do
    enum do
      Navitem.available_icons
    end
  end

def self.available_icons
  [
    ['<i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>',"fa-glass"],
    ["<i class='fa fa-music'></i>","fa-music"],
    ["<i class='fa fa-search'></i>","fa-search"]
  ]
end
```

But the HTML gets escaped and displayed as text.
Is there a way I can output the html without escaping it?

regards Markus

Comment: What file are we looking at there? Knowing how you are laying things out can help us make recommendations for where things should go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)

```
def self.available_icons
  [
    ['<i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.html_safe, "fa-glass"],
    ["<i class='fa fa-music'></i>".html_safe, "fa-music"],
    ["<i class='fa fa-search'></i>".html_safe, "fa-search"]
  ]
end
```